# how to split seekbar into sections

Tags: android, split, seekbar

I need to make seekbar like this[image]

In middle seekbar have 3 small vertical line. I also search on Google but i dont have any idea or key words to do.
Anybody can have me ?
Thank you very much.
Edit: 
I found exactly what i want but it doesnt have any tutorial, so sad.
[image]

I want it like Click slider with my thumb.

Comment: it's really easy: create a custom Drawable that will be passed to `void setProgressDrawable(Drawable d)`

Comment: did you mean that create a file xml in Drawable folder. Please guide me or give me a link have tutorial. I dont know exactly what i can do @@. Sorry if that bothers you.

Comment: no, i mean: class CustomDrawable extends Drawable { ...

Comment: or (which takes less code) use new ShapeDrawable(customShape) with a custom Shape: class CustomShape extends Shape {...

Comment: I found a example like what i want :
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/10/08/inventory-based-discrete-slider/
did you mean that. It seem too difficult for me to apply that :(

Comment: have you created a custom Shape?  if so,  post it

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Pskink very much.
I haved a tour for someday and i can not connect Internet. 
So for my problem, i use your suggest and it worked but I have to wirte too much code to catch event for seekbar if my custom seekbar extend view, shape or something.
Finally, i write : customSeekbar extend Seekbar and override onDraw
 like this :

```
@Override
    protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        seekBarLength=getWidth();
        firstPosition=seekBarLength/3;
        secondPosition=firstPosition*2;
        canvas.drawLine(firstPosition, 0, firstPosition, Res.px(12), linePaint);
        canvas.drawLine(secondPosition, 0, secondPosition, Res.px(12), linePaint);

    }
```

Anyway, thanks for your helps very much.

Comment: can you explain a bit more about doing this?? What is `Res`?

Comment: Res convert dip to pixel. In this code, i use canvas to draw first vertical line at firstposition (x,y) with 
startX The x-coordinate of the start point of the line,

startY The y-coordinate of the start point of the line,

stopX ,

stopY,

paint The paint used to draw the line